# In Dockerfile how to answer option

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to create a docker image from Dockerfile. My Dockerfile sample as follows.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
......
..........
..............
RUN apt install -y aptitude

RUN sh -c '/bin/echo -e "n\ny\ny" | aptitude -f install python-dev'
```

**Error:**

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c sh -c '/bin/echo -e "n\ny\ny" | aptitude -f install python-dev'' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Through dockerfile even i have tried with below. But still no success.

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude -f install python-dev
```

**Error:**

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n (stdin unavailable)
Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude -f install python-dev' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have various dependencies with my application code compilation, Manually inside the docker container i'm able to install using `aptitude -f install python-dev` package without any problem. During installation i need to answer the installation questions like below.

```
aptitude -f install python-dev

no
yes
yes
```

Please give me the solution to answer `yes and No` questions through dockerfile. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to avoid the prompt, or do you want to answer it?

Comment: I want install the package by having the answer in my dockerfile.

Comment: (I'd recommend sticking with `apt-get` for these installs; as @Paolo's answer and several others suggest, use the `apt-get install -y` option.  Don't use higher-level tools like `apt` or `aptitude` in a Dockerfile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-y` option to silently accept the installer prompt:

```
RUN sh -c '/bin/echo -e "n\ny\ny" | aptitude -y -f install python-dev'
```

From `aptitude --help`:

```
-y              Assume that the answer to simple yes/no questions is 'yes'.
```